# React Native ES6 Syntax: Undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I tried out the following example (Fading Hearts) from React Native Playground:
https://rnplay.org/apps/CkBOBQ

The example is written in `createClass` syntax. I converted the same to ES6 syntax where I used classes and methods. The app compiles and opens properly but when I tap on the app, it throws this error:

`Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.state.hearts[i].right')`

There is also a warning:

`Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition`

Part of the code is shown below. If I remove the line `onComplete={this.removeHeart(v.id)}`, there is no error or warning. But this only because we are not properly destroying the heart object. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {hearts: []}
        this.addHeart = this.addHeart.bind(this);
        this.removeHeart = this.removeHeart.bind(this);
    }

    addHeart() {
        startCount += 1;
        this.state.hearts.push({
            id: startCount,
            right: getRandomNumber(50, 150)
        });
        this.setState(this.state);
    }

    removeHeart(v) {
        var index = this.state.hearts.findIndex((heart) => heart.id === v);
        this.state.hearts.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.container} onPress={this.addHeart}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {
                this.state.hearts.map((v, i) =>
                    <AnimatedHeart 
                      key={v.id}
                      onComplete={this.removeHeart(v.id)}
                      style={{right: this.state.hearts[i].right}}
                    />
                , this)
                }
            </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

            <Text style={styles.message}>Tap anywhere to see hearts!</Text>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

[image: Warning screenshot]

Comment: Did you mean `onComplete={e => this.removeHeart(v.id)}`?

Comment: Btw, there's no point in passing `this` to the `map` method when you're using arrow functions anyway, and instead of `this.state.hearts[i].right` you will want to refer to `v.right`

Comment: I tried this suggestion. It makes sense. The error disappears but the animation does not work. I am left with the same warning. It looks like `render` invokes the function.

Comment: Final code, after suggestions from all:              this.state.hearts.map((v, i) =>
                <AnimatedHeart 
                  key={v.id}
                  onComplete={() => this.removeHeart(v.id)}
                  style={{right: v.right}}
                />
              )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are actually invoking the function with your current code. You need to give a function reference to trigger and not actually invoke the function. meaning

`onComplete={this.removeHeart(v.id)}`

should be this

`onComplete={() => this.removeHeart(v.id)}`

when the render cycle goes off it calls the removeHeart function which ends up calling setState while the render is happening `cannot set state in a transition`

Comment: Brilliant! It works! Yes, it must be a callback. Thanks.

Comment: @arvindpdmn awesome glad I could help! good luck with your application :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing argument to removeHeart in the wrong manner

```
       <View style={styles.container}>
            {
            this.state.hearts.map((v, i) =>
                <AnimatedHeart 
                  key={v.id}
                  onComplete={this.removeHeart.bind(this,v.id)}
                  style={{right: this.state.hearts[i].right}}
                />)
            }
        </View>
```

and there is no need to pass `this` to map when you use the arrow function notation

Comment: I can confirm that your answer works as well.Thanks.